# Проблема с подключением процессоров.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ос

Перешёл на Ubuntu и только начал осваиавться в системе. Появился вопрос о подключении всех ядер процессора. Есть что-то похожее на "msconfig", только в Ubuntu???

Comment: с вас что, кто-то вымогает деньги «для задействования намеренно отключенных процессоров, как в ms/windows»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

просмотр информации о процессоре (на примере Ubuntu)

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Еще (cpu0, cpu1, cpuX)

```
ls /sys/devices/system/cpu
```

Отключение ядра процессора

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

Включение ядра процессора

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

Изменения действуют до перезагрузки. Посмотреть, что происходит можно

```
dmesg | grep 'CPU:'
```

увидим, что-то типа

```
[....] CPU 1 is now offline
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял вопрос о работе с низким уровнем, настройкой процессора и ядра. Аналогом `msgonfig` будет `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="...."`
из `/etc/default/grub`. Туда передаются [параметры загрузки ядра системы](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html). Если вы не отключали там ядра процессора, то они все включены.

Если добавить туда `maxcpus=1`, то включится только один процессор при загрузке системы.

По остальным функциям мсконфиг:

Настройку драйверов и сетевого стека делают через `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

Службы управляются через программу `systemctl`.

В `/etc/init` в основном настройка текстовых консолей и запуск инита - лучше там ничего не трогать.

Comment: Я не особо понял, что нужжно там поменять, но в документе находится такое: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Comment: там на самом деле много параметров, начни читать отсюда, если интересно https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html